# How to call multiple templates with iron router

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

I'm totally lost and more I read example or questions and more I'm lost... So the structure of my website is

> client/main.html --in main.js I use `import '../imports/ui/body.js';` to call--> imports/body.html --call--> a lot of templates

And inside the body.html code I have a lot of {{> yield}} (that's just the top of the file)
[image]

Now I need to add iron router to perform a new function and I did that in the router.js file :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'acc'
});
```

And in my body.js file I defined the route:

```
Router.route('/acc');
```

The problem is that when I go on the website it display the main.html + the body.html `<header>` only ! (you can see in the code there is a template calling {{> ajoutement}} and this one is displayed but the next one out of the header {{> instagramfeed }} isn't for example.)

Someone could help me to figure out why my template calling doesn't work anymore ?

Maybe it could help you to see the website without iron router:
[image]
And what I explained when I use iron router:
[image]

[EDIT] someone asked for the helper and the events so :

Helper body.js:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  //permet de lire les informations des articles pour les afficher de plus récent au plus ancien dans le template article.html
  articles() {
    return Articles.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  //permet de voir si la valeur 'wantModif' est true --> va permettre d'afficher le formulaire plus loin
  wantModif: function() {
    return Session.get('wantModif');
  },
  idTemp: function(){
    return Session.get('idTemp');
  },
  wantLoc: function(){
    return Session.get('wantLoc');
  },
  where: function(){
   return Session.get('city') + " [" + Session.get('state') + "] " + Session.get('country');
  },
  wantInsta: function(){
    return Session.get('wantInsta');
  },
  city: function(){
    return Session.get('city');
  },
});
```

Event are really too big so I just put a link to [the code](http://collabedit.com/pbwm4)

Comment: Any help ? I can't call my templates and the subscribe method don't work too... but without iron router all work perfectly and I need it to add a function

Answer (score 0):

It's just because wantInsta is returning false

Comment: Yes it's what it need to return unless we click on a specific button, but bellow this template calling there are others template calling who should be there like {{>article}} (we can see on the 1st screenshot the article) and in the first screenshot 'wantInsta' returned false too

Comment: Can you add your helpers and events  ?

Comment: It's done I hope it could help you but I don't think so because I do nothing with the route in the helper or the events